# CMake linking 2 libraries with relative path

Tags: c++, cmake

my project structure:

```
...
CMakeLists.txt
src/
    project/
        libA/
            CMakeLists.txt
            libA.h
            libA.cpp
        libB/
            CMakeLists.txt
            libB.h
            libB.cpp        
build/
```

CMakelists.txt

```
project(project)

# set some global dirs
set(LIB_A_DIR "src/project/libA")
set(LIB_B_DIR "src/project/libB")

# include header directories
include_directories(${LIB_A_DIR})
include_directories(${LIB_B_DIR})

# generating linkable libraries
add_subdirectory(${LIB_A_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${LIB_B_DIR})
```

src/project/libA/CMakeLists.txt

```
# define libA sources
set(LIB_A_SOURCES libA.cpp libA.h)

# generate libA library
add_library(libA SHARED ${LIB_A_SOURCES})
```

src/project/libB/CMakeLists.txt

```
# define libB sources
set(LIB_B_SOURCES libB.cpp libB.h)

# generate libB library
add_library(libB SHARED ${LIB_B_SOURCES})

# link libraries
target_link_libraries(libB PRIVATE libA)
```

now if i run `cmake .. && make` from the build folder any function call made from `libB` works just fine. But as soon as i want to move this file structure the link breaks.

For example when i did `cp -r build/ build_copy/` and clear the `build` directory with `rm -rf build/*` any code that includes libB throws a `error while loading shared libraries: liblibB.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

how do i get my link to use the relative file path?

*side note: i need them to be 2 seperate shared libraries combined with a link*

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the *runtime-path* of `libA` to where it is installed. This is done with the `-rpath` linker option.

Since the C++ frontend `g++` or `clang++` will be used when linking, you need to use the `-Wl` flag to pass the `-rpath` option to the linker.

You can set flag with the [`LINK_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS.html) target property for `libB` with the [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) command:

```
set_target_properties(libB
    PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/libA/installation")
```

Comment: will this work with `-rpath,../libA` ? if so what file does this belong in? the CMakelists for libB?

Comment: @user2255757 No, it really needs to be an absolute path. There's plenty of [CMake variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) that can be used to help you with that.

Comment: @Some programmer dude RPATH can be relative. `$ORIGIN`, for example, wouldn't be very useful otherwise.

Comment: @JesperJuhl do you know a way to incorporate a cmake command into my libB CMakeLists such that it can use ../libA to find libA no matter where this file structure may be located? not sure what `$ORIGIN` is `echo $ORIGIN` does nothing

Comment: @JesperJuhl Only as long as the relative paths remains consistent. So if `libB` is moved, then `libA` must follow along. Using absolute paths one can move `libB` without moving `libA`. The opposite is not possible though.

Comment: @Some programmer dude obviously. But it's still quite useful to set rpath to something like `$ORIGIN/../lib64` when you have a install structure like /opt/myapp/bin/myapp and libs in /opt/myapp/lib64/libmylib.so etc, since then the /opt/myapp folder as an entity becomes relocatable.

Answer (score 1):

as in [CMake linking 2 libraries with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190277/cmake-linking-2-libraries-with-relative-path#comment87398242_50190376) comment:

Assign a variable with the absolute path of the relative path to the library:

```
get_filename_component(LIB_A_PATH ../lib/liba.a ABSOLUTE)
```

Then use the absolute path to link the lib (here statically):

```
add_library( lib_a STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_a PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_A_PATH})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib_a)
```